# c++: return struct from function in class in another file "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, struct, reference

So, essentially I am attempting to create this very basic program which calculates the volume of a prism. This is for learning purposes only so I am trying some unnecessarily advanced "maneuvers".

The idea is to call a function "dims()" in the class "vol" in the file "vol.cpp", which collects the dimensions from 'cin >>' and puts them in a struct, which is declared in the header file "vol.h". This struct is then returned.
Another function in "vol" called "volume" is then called with the elements of the struct as arguments, which then calculates the volume and returns the value.

I have done a lot of researching and debugging. I've had so many errors, but I can't shake this last (i hope) one.

I keep getting this error:

> undefined reference to `vol::dims()'

at line 10 in main.cpp `priv_dims = oneObject.dims();`

Please help.

The main.cpp code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vol.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vol oneObject;
    vol::dimensions priv_dims;
    priv_dims = oneObject.dims();

    double calcVolume = oneObject.volume(priv_dims.height, priv_dims.width, priv_dims.length);
    cout << calcVolume;

    return 0;
}
```

The vol.h code is:

```
#ifndef VOL_H
#define VOL_H

class vol
{
    public:
        struct dimensions
        {
            double length, height, width;
        };
        vol();
        double volume(double h=5, double w=5, double l=5 );
        dimensions dims();

    private:
};

#endif // VOL_H
```

And the vol.cpp code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "vol.h"

vol::vol()
{
    //ctor
}

double vol::volume(double h, double w, double l)
{
    return h*w*l;
}

vol::dimensions dims()
{
    vol::dimensions dims_priv;

    std::cout << "Please enter length: ";
    std::cin >> dims_priv.length;
    std::cout << "Please enter width: ";
    std::cin >> dims_priv.width;
    std::cout << "Please enter height: ";
    std::cin >> dims_priv.height;

    return dims_priv;

}
```

I really hope you can help me as nailing this functionality probably will turn out to be pretty useful to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vol.cpp, this line:

```
vol::dimensions dims()
```

should be:

```
vol::dimensions vol::dims()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not defining the member function correctly, but defining it as a non-member function.

change

```
vol::dimensions dims()
```

to

```
vol::dimensions vol::dims()
//              ~~~~~
```